# SQLite possibility to join matching Rows into one?

Tags: sqlite, left-join

I have a n:m relation of following tables:

```
Game
  g_id
  g_name

Player
  p_id
  p_name

GamePlayer
  gp_id
  gp_p_id
  gp_g_id
```

And a Query like this:

```
SELECT g_name, p_name 
FROM GamePlayer 
INNER JOIN Game ON g_id = gp_g_id
INNER JOIN Player ON p_id = gp_p_id;
```

this will return a Row for each entry inside `GamePlayer`. If I have two Games with three players each, this query will return 6 Rows with the name of the Game and the Player (where there are obviously only two different Game names), which looks like this:

```
GameName1   John
GameName1   Dan
GameName1   Phil
GameName2   Dan
GameName2   Pete
GameName2   Kate
```

I like to have ( in this case ) two Rows which are looking like this:

```
GameName1   John   Dan   Phil
GameName2   Dan    Pete  Kate
```

is this somehow possible?

Note:
There may be more than three Players in a Game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating columns based on data would require some kind of pivot function, which SQLite does not have.

What you can do is to use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) to merge multiple values into one column value:

```
SELECT g_name,
       group_concat(p_name)
FROM Game
JOIN GamePlayer ON g_id = gp_g_id
JOIN Player ON gp_p_id = p_id
GROUP BY g_name
```